# How do I block VPN requests for SOME Lambdas? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, vpn, amazon-waf

I know that WAF has a managed group rule that blocks VPN requests, but that's not what I want.
I want to block VPN requests to just some lamdas. I'm using AppSync, not API Gateway and I'm using CDK.

I tried to add customRequestHandling but that didn't do anything. I think you can't modify or add the headers in managed rule.

Comment: Are you open to splitting your Lambda functions into two groups? One group of functions will fall under the WAF-protected API gateways and one group would be under a WAF-less function?

Comment: Presume you are referring to the [Anonymous IP List](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/aws-waf-adds-anonymous-ip-list-for-aws-managed-rules/) managed rule.